# Which is the best method to store friendlist in php?

Tags: php, xml, database, relationship

In order to implement friends list method in my webpage,

**Which is the best way to store friends list in php?**

My options are

**Database** See ***[this Link](http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/837763-storing-list-data-mysql)***

or

create a **separate folder for each user and store an xml file** which contains that user's friendslist.

Please do suggest me the best one?

If anyone has other logic.let me know about it.

Comment: Please define "best". "Best" using what criteria?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572335/xml-flat-file-vs-relational-database-backend

Comment: @deceze Best according to data manipulation and handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want to give better criteria for "best" - performance, maintainability, scalability, flexibility?

You also would help us by explaining how you intend to use those friend lists - that allows us to see if the proposals make sense.

Having said that....

I'd recommend a database. That way, you store the relationship and can reason about it in a single place - for instance, you can find out if Alice is friends with Bob, and whether Bob is friends with Alice (in the text file scheme, you'd have to store this information in the "Alice" and "Bob" text files, which makes checking a pain, especially for large groups of people).

You can also easily find friend chains, so you can suggest friends (if Alice is friends with Bob and Chuck, she may know other people who are friends with both Bob and Chuck).

Finally, you get the other benefits of databases - performance when dealing with multiple concurrent users, ACID etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that database option, as described in the link in your question.  In particular, the database schema in which the users table is separate from the relationship table.  You'll find things like deleting friendships much easier and more efficient.

Comment: +1, processing XML in real-time is also much slower than using a database.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend to use SQLLIte or text files for small jobs like this.

Comment: What if it needs to handle more data